# How to prove that point $P$ is collinear with $A$ and $B$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Referred to the origin $O$, $A$ and $B$ are two points which have position vectors **a** and **b** respectively.

Prove  that the point $P$ whose position vector **p** is given by **p**=$\lambda $**a** $+ (1-\lambda)$**b** is collinear with $A$ and $B$.

From the ratio theorem, I know that if a point $P$ divides a line $AB$ in the ratio $\lambda:\mu$, then $\overrightarrow {OP}= \displaystyle\frac{\lambda b +\mu a }{\lambda+\mu}$.

In this case, I know that $P$ lies on $AB$ such that $AP:PB=\lambda:1-\lambda$, but how do I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite the equality

**p**=$\lambda $**a** $+ (1-\lambda)$**b**

as

$p-b = \lambda (a-b) $

which is the same as

$\overrightarrow {BP} = \lambda \overrightarrow {BA} $

which gives you that the 3 points are collinear.

Alternatively (if you're still not convinced): pick the point $M$ such that $M$ lies on $AB$ and divides it in a ratio $\lambda : 1-\lambda$. Then prove that $\overrightarrow {OM} = \overrightarrow{OP}$.

But the last gives you that $M$ and $P$ coincide, and so $P$ also lies on $AB$ (because of how you chose $M$).

*I mean, this statement is trivial which (ironically) kind of makes it hard to prove if one gets somewhat confused about what is known already and what needs to be proved.*

Answer (score 0):

A general point on the line $AB$ has position vector $$\mathbf p = \mathbf b+ \lambda (\mathbf a - \mathbf b) = \lambda \mathbf a + (1 - \lambda) \mathbf b$$
Since to be on the line we can first go to $B$ and then travel any distance in the direction parallel to $AB$.
Or, if you like, take that formula as given and note that $AP$ and $PB$ are both parallel to $AB$.